# connect to svn server with tk domain

Tags: svn, version-control, dns, raspberry-pi, nameservers

I am hosting a subversion server on my raspberry pi.
(not an apache svn server. just svnserve)
How can i use a .tk domain that i created to connect to my svn server.

I am able to connect to is using my public ip but i would like to be able to use the domain i created. i cant seem to find how to do it.
Do i need to configure the nameservers somewhere?

Or do i need to configure something in my domain settings?

my raspberry pi runs debian.

If someone know how to do this. please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll own the domain name you should login to your registrar, then go to the manage DNS settings page.

You'll need to create an A record pointing to your public ip.

Cheers